# Show and Hide action bar buttons outside onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In the overrided `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`  I can easily hide or show menu buttons simply adding true or false in this way

```
menu.findItem(R.id.my_action_button).setVisible(true);
```

but I need to do the same operation also when a different method inside the activity is called,

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call:

```
    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```